# How to change the inner color (NOT Forecolor or Backcolor property) of a check box in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, checkbox, background-color

I want to change the inner color of the checkbox. This question is not regarding forecolor or backcolor.

Please click on This [Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bnmc.png) see the image

Comment: You can have a look at bootstrap: http://www.cssscript.com/pretty-checkbox-radio-inputs-bootstrap-awesome-bootstrap-checkbox-css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution is not to use checkbox control at all. Better use your own images for checked/unchecked state on-top of hyperlink or image element.